# TouchID: What's the difference between fallback (enter password) and cancel?

Tags: ios8, touch-id

I'm integrating TouchID into my app, but I don't get the difference between the two buttons `enter password` and `cancel`. They result in an error of `LAErrorUserCancel` or `LAErrorUserFallback`, but I can't handle them differently, so I'd like to avoid one of the two buttons. Is there a way to do this? Or what's the best practice here?

1Password is an example here; both buttons the user gets presented are leading to the same action - that you have to enter the password into the app manually. In my opinion it would make sense to have only one button here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is super easy to remove the "Enter Password" button if you don't need it for your application. Just set the *localizedFallbackTitle* property to an empty string, not nil, and the button will not be display.

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"";
```

(You can't also set it to something more appropriate for your application if you need to, just put the string in there.)

Note: to actually answer the question as posted, not to answer the comment that that OP left on the other answer... the fallback case is useful when the user has decided to not use TouchID but would rather enter a password to gain access to your locked service. You would test for this in the *evaluatePolicy* message.

Answer (score 1):

If the touchID alert view is displayed from the same VC that contains the password field, both options would accomplish the same. But think in cases where you have workflow where you can cancel the full authentication operation (LAErrorUserCancel) or display a login view controller(LAErrorUserFallback).

Comment: okay, thanks a lot. Is it possible to hide one of the two buttons?